# Is this the right way to create a many-to-many relationship with extra fields in fuelphp

Tags: php, mysql, orm, fuelphp

There doesnt seem to be much documentation on creating a many-to-many relationship that also includes extra fields (so its not just the IDs of the two models). As far as I understand there needs to be another Model inbetween which will have the additional fields (as the relationship itself doesnt support it).

Is this the right way to do it?

```
class Model_Ab
{
  protected static $_belongs_to = array('a', 'b');

  //this has the additional fields
}

class Model_A
{
  protected static $_has_many = array('ab');
}

class Model_B
{
  protected static $_has_many = array('ab');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FuelPHP's ORM doesn't support any additional columns in the many to many table. Off course you can make a workaround:

```
modelA -> has_one <=> has_many model_through -> has_many <=> has_one modelB
```

Comment: Dont fully understand what your example means, can you make this example in a similar format as the one in the OP, showing the models and the relationship variable in each.